# lein ring server does not automatically rebuild

Tags: clojure, leiningen, compojure, hiccup, cljsbuild

I am writing a small clojurescript project and I followed the numerous lein cljsbuild examples that use lein ring as a development web server.

I used to run `lein ring server` to serve the website on my local machine. Now it seems that lein ring server does not automatically rebuild and restart when I change the clj files that contain the hiccup html definitions.

According to https://github.com/weavejester/lein-ring this should be the case (maybe I have misread, but it says that reloading should be the default).

My project.cljs is more or less equivalent to https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild/blob/master/example-projects/advanced/project.clj

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried setting auto-reload? to true?

Comment: I did `  :ring {:auto-reload? true ...` though I have no confirmation that this is the right invocation.

Comment: I have just increased the version numbers of all clojar packages in the leiningen project file and now it seems to work.

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same problem and ends up the cause was that I was requiring a library before declaring  the namespace, requiring it the line below the namespace made it work.
So it was like:

```
(require 'clojure.pprint)
(ns app.core)
```

and I changed to:

```
(ns app.core)
(require 'clojure.pprint)
```